# Wordpress compilation of a "complete" .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, security, .htaccess

I was cleaning up some stuff and making some files generic so I can take them of the shelve when I need them. But I have a .htaccess questions.

<strike>**Question #1**</strike> [Answered by @Kanu]

At the start of the file I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Further on I have a snippet that blocks hotlinking:

```
#Switch on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
#Allow empty referrals, in case visitors are using personal firewalls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#Match request URL. Replace www.yourwebsite.com with your website URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?www.yourwebsite.com [NC]
#Match all files with the below list of extensions
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Does it hurt to do

```
RewriteEngine On
```

twice or can I skip the second RewriteEnginge? What is the best practice here?

<strike>**Question #2:**</strike> [Answered by @Kanu]
Also, do I start with the WP part or do I need to end with it?

There are some more things I do in the htacces like only giving certain IP's access to the admin, protecting; htaccess|htpasswd|log|ini. Do you have some more advice or pointers, think of security or any other nifty stuff.

Thanks, /Paul

**ADDED: 14th of june 2013**

Thinking of adding this to stop spammers, idea's, due I found this on a relative old [post](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/cool-wordpress-htaccess-tips-to-boost-your-wordpress-sites-security-1676).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*yourblog.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

Canonicalization via HTACCESS for stopping malicious behaviour via bots and evil scripts. Also so that search engines find their way arround. Found this [here](http://john.do/more-wordpress-security/).

```
#favicon
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /favicon(s)?\.?(gif|ico|jpe?g?|png)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://your-domain-name.com/favicon.ico [R=301,L]

#robots.txt
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://your-domain-name.com/robots.txt [R=301,L]

#sitemap
RedirectMatch 301 /sitemap\.xml$ http://your-domain-name.com/sitemap.xml
RedirectMatch 301 /sitemap\.xml\.gz$ http://your-domain-name.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

#### I'll post the complete .htaccess file here and update any good stuff for use.

```
# ==================================================================
# WORDPRESS
# ==================================================================

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress

# ==================================================================
# RESTRICT ACCESS IP BASED
# ==================================================================

    order deny,allow
    # enter name here and replace xxx.xxx.x.x with IP
    allow from xxx.xxx.x.x
    # enter name here and replace xxx.xxx.x.x with IP
    allow from xxx.xxx.x.x
    # enter name here and replace xxx.xxx.x.x with IP
    allow from xxx.xxx.x.x
    deny from all

# ==================================================================
# PROTECT FILES, THANKS KANU: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1089399/kanu
# ==================================================================

    #Protect some files from direct access
    <FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|install\.php|php\.info|readme\.html|bb-config\.php|\.htaccess|\.htpasswd|readme\.txt|timthumb\.php|error_log|error\.log|PHP_errors\.log|\.svn)">
    Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

# ==================================================================
# DISABLE TRACE TRACK REQUESTS, THANKS KANU: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1089399/kanu
# ==================================================================

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

# ==================================================================
# PREVENT HOTLINKING
# ==================================================================

    #Switch on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine on
    #Allow empty referrals, in case visitors are using personal firewalls
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    #Match request URL. Replace www.yourwebsite.com with your website URL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?www.yourwebsite.com [NC]
    #Match all files with the below list of extensions
    RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# ==================================================================
# DISABLE DIRECTORY BROWSING
# ==================================================================

    Options All -Indexes

# ==================================================================
# DISABLE SERVER SIGNATURE, THANKS KANU: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1089399/kanu
# ==================================================================   

    ServerSignature Off

# ==================================================================
# DENY SOME KNOWN BAD BOTS, THANKS KANU: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1089399/kanu
# ==================================================================   
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: OP, you should create a complete question and then accept the answer when someone gives it to you. Please accept @Kanu's answer and start a  new question.

Comment: ok, I now notice I did it wrong, Im waiting till its revisited

Comment: yeah stupid me, I edited Kanu's answer instead of my question. I need to wait till a moderator fixes my stupidity?

Comment: and do I need to make a new question, or can I leave this one intact and continue on here?

Comment: You can go ahead and edit your question to comment on the correct answer, or expand upon the explanation. The idea, though, was just to make sure that the correct answer got its due without having to endlessly expand on your original question's follow-ups. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring "RewriteEngine On" twice will not hurt

For Question2 You do not need start or end with WP

I am using some extra codes for security

```
# Disable server signature 
ServerSignature Off

#Protect some files from direct access
<FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|install\.php|php\.info|readme\.html|bb-config\.php|\.htaccess|readme\.txt|timthumb\.php|error_log|error\.log|PHP_errors\.log|\.svn)">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Disable trace track requests
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Deny some known bad bots
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
# END bots
```

Comment: have added your input with compliments!

Comment: sorry @Kanu, I messed up your answer by editing it. I thought I edited my question.

Comment: Quick question, why deny access to timthumb.php? Wouldn't that make it impossible to use directly in the `src` attribue?